# Submit button not working with wtforms , no post request sent to the server. How to solve this?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am new to programming and Flask. I am trying to create a chatroom type app for which initially I have to create a user Register and login system but I am facing issues with the on submitting the form.
The submit button that I am using with Wtforms does absolutely nothing, neither sends any post request to the server.
Please assist!

```py
    from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect, url_for
    from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField
    from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo
    
    class RegisterForm(Form):
        name = StringField('Name', validators=[Length(min=1, max=50)])
        username = StringField('Username', validators=[Length(min=3, max=50)])
        email = StringField('Email', validators=[Length(min=7, max=50)])
        password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('confirm', message='Password do not match!')])
        confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password')
    
    @app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def register():
        form = RegisterForm(request.form)
        if request.method =='POST' and form.validate():
            name = form.name.data
            username = form.username.data
            email = form.email.data
            password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))
    
            #create cursor
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    
            #Executing the Query
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, username, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, username, email, password))
    
            #commit to DB
            mysql.connection.commit()
            #close cursor
            cur.close()
    
            flash('You have registered to the Chatter!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    
        return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

The HTML code:

```
    {% extends 'layout.html' %}
    {% block content  %}
        <h2 style="color: brown;">Register to Join the chatroom!</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('register') }}">
            {{ form.csrf_token }} 
            {{form.name.label}}
            {{form.name}}
            {{form.username.label}}
            {{form.username}}
            {{form.password.label}}
            {{form.password}}
            {{form.confirm.label}}
            {{form.confirm}}  
        </form>
        <p><input type="submit", name="submit"></p>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Put the submit button inside the form tags.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have a submit button in the form.

Add this to RegisterForm :
`submit = SubmitField('Sign Up!')`

Add this to the HTML code :
`{{form.submit}}`

Also don't use SQL like a barbarian. Use Flask-SQLAlchemy. You'll be in heaven.